# Problems with creating custom control in JavaFx

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to create a custom control in JavaFx. The main aim is to create a node that acts as a button. It is simply a Label that would be styled with css to look like a button. I have created a class `MyControl` that extends the control class like so:

```
public class MyControl extends Control {


@Override
protected String getUserAgentStylesheet() {
    return MyControl.class.getResource("myControl.css").toExternalForm();
}

public MyControl() {
    getStyleClass().add("new-control");
}
public MyControl(String item) {
    getStyleClass().add("new-control");
}
}
}
```

For the SkinBase class `MyControlSkin` I have:

```
public class MyControlSkin extends SkinBase<MyControlSkin> {
    public MyControlSkin(MyControlSkin control) {
        super(control);
        Label label = new Label("Some text here");

        getChildren.add(label);

    }
}
```

In the `myControl.css` file i simply have:

```
.tree-node-view {
   -fx-skin: "treeviewsample.TreeViewSkin";
}
.label {
    -fx-text-fill: -fx-text-background-color;
}
```

I have created the css for this but the problem is that I don't see the label displayed on the scene:

```
MyControl control = new MyControl();
```

but no Label displays on the screen. Please help me I am new to this so ask me for more information if in case my question does not make sense.

I am using javaFx 2.2

Comment: Can you show myControl.css?

Comment: I have added the css file myControl.css

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if you made errors transferring the code from your IDE to the post, but as it stands the skin class will not compile. You need

```
public class MyControlSkin extends SkinBase<MyControl> {
    public MyControlSkin(MyControl control) {
        super(control);
        Label label = new Label("Some text here");

        getChildren().add(label);

    }
}
```

The css must define an `fx:skin` property for a class that matches the control. So you need

```
.new-control {
   -fx-skin: "MyControlSkin";
}
.label {
    -fx-text-fill: -fx-text-background-color;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I copied it wrong. The  css `-fx-skin` property was linking to the wrong file. Thanks.